# How to get the cutted column range in ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I want to apply data validation and styling to a column range, but without the header cell. Now I'm doing it in two steps:

- Apply rules to a column range
- Clear the header cell

It works, but I have to edit header cells after all other cells. And it looks like a hack, there might be a nicer way.

So, how to select the column without a top cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of the last row you want to style, you could use a `Range()` like this:

```
worksheet.Range(2, col1, row, col2).Style....;
```

If not you could get the `Cells()` from your column range and skip the first row like this:

```
worksheet.Columns(col1, col2).Cells().Where(c => c.WorksheetRow().RowNumber() != 1).Style....;
```

Comment: Filtering and editing all cells from the second to the bottom is very expensive operation. Code runs for minutes and the result file is about 10MB. That's obviosly a wrong way

Comment: Try using `CellsUsed()` instead of `Cells()`.

Comment: No cells are used yet

Comment: Then there isn't a better alternative to your original method, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

If myRange is your column original range (including header row), how about:

```
var rangeWithoutHeader = worksheet.Range(myRange.FirstCell().CellBelow(), myRange.LastCell());
```